# How to mitigate a forkbomb in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, process, fork

Fork bomb `:(){ :|:& };:`, a bash function producing DoS (Denial of Service) and crashes the system.

How do we mitigate this?

One way is to limit the processes per user through `/etc/security/limits.conf`

Anything else?

Comment: It looks like the way to go. Related: [How to protect Ubuntu from fork bomb](http://askubuntu.com/a/23535/143251) and [How to prevent fork bomb?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/85411/40596). The second one mentions something important _[...] root can always fork processes.. If some software is not trusted, it should not run as root anyway._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in [How to prevent fork bomb?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/85411/40596), editing ulimit and sysctl is the way to go.

However, for `root` this does not work:

> The superuser or any process with the CAP_SYS_ADMIN or
>   CAP_SYS_RESOURCE capabilities are not affected by that limitation,
>   that's not something that can be changed. `root` can always fork
>   processes.
>
> If some software is not trusted, it should not run as `root` anyway.